# SQL Server 2012 query / Job

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a pretty complex SQL query that I need run every Monday morning (early).

I've gotten the SQL query to give me the data I need but i'm at a loss how to have the query insert the results into a table.

The declare statements are causing the issue (I THINK)

Does anyone have any ideas? Ideally I'd like to setup a job that just runs and appends to a table.

Thanks.
K.

```
DECLARE @StartDateTime     DATETIME;
DECLARE @EndDateTime       DATETIME;
DECLARE @ReportOn          CHAR(1);
DECLARE @Group1            VARCHAR(25);
DECLARE @Group2            VARCHAR(25);
DECLARE @Date1Grouping     VARCHAR(25);
DECLARE @Date2Grouping     VARCHAR(25);
DECLARE @DivisionID        VARCHAR(10);
DECLARE @GroupSubsidiaries BIT;

SET @StartDateTime     = '3/06/2013'  ;
SET @EndDateTime       = '3/12/2013' ;
SET @ReportOn          = 'S'          ;
SET @Group1            = 'Due Date'   ;
SET @Group2            = 'Sale Date'  ;
SET @Date1Grouping     = 'Yearly'     ;
SET @Date2Grouping     = 'Daily'      ; 
SET @GroupSubsidiaries = 1            ;

DECLARE @GLEntries TABLE (ID INT PRIMARY KEY, Amount FLOAT, EntryDateTime     DATETIME, GLClassificationType INT, 
                      GroupID INT, GLAccountID INT, GLAccountClassTypeID  INT, AccountID INT, 
                      TransHeaderID INT, TransDetailID INT, DivisionID INT, 
                      Classification INT, IsTaxable BIT, TaxClassID INT,
                      GoodsItemID INT, GoodsItemClassTypeID INT);

--   'C' used for Closed Reports
IF ( @ReportOn = 'C' )
INSERT INTO @GLEntries
SELECT GL.ID, GL.Amount, GL.EntryDateTime, GL.GLClassificationType, 
     GL.GroupID, GL.GLAccountID, GL.GLAccountClassTypeID, GL.AccountID, 
     GL.TransactionID, GL.TransDetailID, GL.DivisionID, 
     GL.Classification, GL.IsTaxable, GL.TaxClassID,
     GL.GoodsItemID, GL.GoodsItemClassTypeID
FROM   GL WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE  (GL.GLAccountID <> 53)
     AND EXISTS( SELECT 1 
                 FROM TransHeader 
                 WHERE ClosedDate BETWEEN @StartDateTime and @EndDateTime
                       AND ID = GL.TransactionID )

ELSE
INSERT INTO @GLEntries
SELECT GL.ID, GL.Amount, GL.EntryDateTime, GL.GLClassificationType, 
     GL.GroupID, GL.GLAccountID, GL.GLAccountClassTypeID, GL.AccountID, 
     GL.TransactionID, GL.TransDetailID, GL.DivisionID, 
     GL.Classification, GL.IsTaxable, GL.TaxClassID,
     GL.GoodsItemID, GL.GoodsItemClassTypeID
FROM   GL WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE  (GL.GLAccountID <> 53)
     AND GL.EntryDateTime between @StartDateTime and @EndDateTime
;



SELECT Orders.*, Totals.*,
   ( SELECT -Sum(Amount) 
     FROM   @GLEntries GL1 
            LEFT JOIN TransHeader TH ON (TH.ID = GL1.TransHeaderID)
     WHERE  GL1.GLClassificationType = 2005)

    as TotalTaxes,

    @StartDateTime  as theStartDate,
    @EndDateTime as theEndDate,
   -- Selects Group1 based on @Group1
   CASE
     WHEN @Group1 = 'Product'  THEN Product 
     WHEN @Group1 = 'None'     THEN 'None'
     WHEN @Group1 = 'Due Date' THEN 
       CASE
         WHEN @Date1Grouping = 'Daily'   THEN Convert( VARCHAR(25),   Orders.DueDate, 112)
         WHEN @Date1Grouping = 'Weekly'  THEN Convert( VARCHAR(25), DateAdd(d, -DatePart(dw,Orders.DueDate) + 1, Orders.DueDate), 112 )
         WHEN @Date1Grouping = 'Monthly' THEN Cast( DatePart(yyyy, Orders.DueDate) * 100 + DatePart(mm,Orders.DueDate) AS VARCHAR(7) )
         WHEN @Date1Grouping = 'Yearly'  THEN Cast( DatePart(yyyy, Orders.DueDate) AS VARCHAR(4) )
       END
     WHEN @Group1 = 'Sales Date' THEN 
       CASE
         WHEN @Date1Grouping = 'Daily'   THEN Convert( VARCHAR(25), Orders.EntryDateTime, 112 )
         WHEN @Date1Grouping = 'Weekly'  THEN Convert( VARCHAR(25), DateAdd(d, -DatePart(dw,Orders.EntryDateTime) + 1, Orders.EntryDateTime), 112 )
         WHEN @Date1Grouping = 'Monthly' THEN Cast( DatePart(yyyy, Orders.EntryDateTime) * 100 + DatePart(mm, Orders.EntryDateTime) AS VARCHAR(7) )
         WHEN @Date1Grouping = 'Yearly'  THEN Cast( DatePart(yyyy, Orders.EntryDateTime) AS VARCHAR(4) )
       END
     WHEN @Group1 = 'Primary Salesperson'     THEN Salesperson1LastName + Salesperson1FirstName 
     WHEN @Group1 = 'Customer Origin'         THEN OriginName
     WHEN @Group1 = 'Industry'                THEN IndustryName
     WHEN @Group1 = 'Order Origin'            THEN OrderOriginName
     WHEN @Group1 = 'Postal Code'             THEN PostalCode
     WHEN @Group1 = 'Postal Code 3 Digit'     THEN PostalCode3Digit
     WHEN @Group1 = 'Product Category'        THEN ProductCategory
     WHEN @Group1 = 'Account'                 THEN AccountName
     WHEN @Group1 = 'Company Name'            THEN CompanyName
     WHEN @Group1 = 'Company Frequency'       THEN CompanyName
     WHEN @Group1 = 'Company Volume'          THEN CompanyName
     WHEN @Group1 = 'GL Department'           THEN GLDepartment
     WHEN @Group1 = 'Industry (Parent)'       THEN IndustryParent
     WHEN @Group1 = 'Company Origin (Parent)' THEN CompanyOriginParent
     WHEN @Group1 = 'Order Origin (Parent)'   THEN OrderOriginParent
     WHEN @Group1 = 'Region'                            THEN RegionName
   END AS Group1,

   CASE 
     WHEN @Group2 = 'Product'  THEN Product
     WHEN @Group2 = 'None'     THEN 'None'
     WHEN @Group2 = 'Due Date' THEN 
       CASE
         WHEN @Date2Grouping = 'Daily'   THEN Convert( VARCHAR(25), Orders.DueDate, 112 )
         WHEN @Date2Grouping = 'Weekly'  THEN Convert( VARCHAR(25), DateAdd(d, -DatePart(dw, Orders.DueDate) + 1, Orders.DueDate), 112 )
         WHEN @Date2Grouping = 'Monthly' THEN Cast( DatePart(yyyy, Orders.DueDate) * 100 + DatePart(mm, Orders.DueDate) AS VARCHAR(7) )
         WHEN @Date2Grouping = 'Yearly'  THEN Cast( DatePart(yyyy, Orders.DueDate) AS VARCHAR(4) )
       END
     WHEN @Group2 = 'Sales Date' THEN 
       CASE
         WHEN @Date2Grouping = 'Daily'   THEN Convert( VARCHAR(25), Orders.EntryDateTime, 112 )
         WHEN @Date2Grouping = 'Weekly'  THEN Convert( VARCHAR(25), DateAdd(d, -DatePart(dw, Orders.EntryDateTime) + 1, Orders.EntryDateTime), 112 )
         WHEN @Date2Grouping = 'Monthly' THEN Cast( DatePart(yyyy, Orders.EntryDateTime) * 100 + DatePart(mm, Orders.EntryDateTime) AS VARCHAR(7) )
         WHEN @Date2Grouping = 'Yearly'  THEN Cast( DatePart(yyyy, Orders.EntryDateTime) AS VARCHAR(4) )
       END
     WHEN @Group2 = 'Primary Salesperson' THEN Salesperson1LastName + Salesperson1FirstName 
     WHEN @Group2 = 'Customer Origin'     THEN OriginName
     WHEN @Group2 = 'Industry'            THEN IndustryName
     WHEN @Group2 = 'Order Origin'        THEN OrderOriginName
     WHEN @Group2 = 'Postal Code'         THEN PostalCode
     WHEN @Group2 = 'Postal Code 3 Digit' THEN PostalCode3Digit
     WHEN @Group2 = 'Product Category'    THEN ProductCategory
     WHEN @Group2 = 'Account'             THEN AccountName
     WHEN @Group2 = 'Company'             THEN CompanyName
     WHEN @Group2 = 'GL Department'       THEN GLDepartment
     WHEN @Group2 = 'Region'                            THEN RegionName
   END AS Group2 

FROM ( SELECT 1 AS StoreID,
          fx_Return.DivisionID,
          EmployeeGroup.DivisionName,
          fx_Return.TransHeaderID,
          fx_Return.OrderNumber,
          fx_Return.InvoiceNumber,
          fx_Return.CompanyName,
          -fx_Return.GLAmount AS Amount,
          GLAccount.AccountName,
          fx_Return.StatusText,
          fx_Return.Classification,
          fx_Return.GLClassificationType,
          fx_Return.Description,
          fx_Return.EntryDateTime,
          fx_Return.DiscountPrice,
          fx_Return.SaleDate,
          fx_Return.DueDate,
          fx_Return.BuiltDate,
          fx_Return.OrderCreatedDate,
          fx_Return.ClosedDate,
          fx_Return.AccountID,
          fx_Return.GLDepartment,
          fx_Return.SalesPerson1ID,
          SalesPerson1.FirstName AS SalesPerson1FirstName,
          SalesPerson1.LastName AS SalesPerson1LastName,
          Origin.ItemName AS OriginName,        
          CASE
            WHEN Origin.ParentID = 11 THEN Origin.ItemName
            ELSE CompanyOriginParent.ItemName
          END AS CompanyOriginParent,
          Industry.ItemName AS IndustryName,
          CASE
            WHEN IndustryParent.ID = 10 THEN Industry.ItemName
            ELSE IndustryParent.ItemName
          END AS IndustryParent,
          fx_Return.OrderOriginName,
          CASE 
            WHEN OrderOrigin.ParentID = 13 THEN OrderOrigin.ItemName
            ELSE OrderOriginParent.ItemName
          END AS OrderOriginParent,
          Address.PostalCode,
          SUBSTRING(Address.PostalCode,1,3) AS PostalCode3Digit,
          Product.ItemName AS Product,
          ProductCategory.ElementName AS ProductCategory,
          ProductSubCategory.ElementName AS ProductSubCategory,
          Region.ItemName AS RegionName

    FROM ( SELECT GL2.EntryDateTime, 
                 SUM( CASE
                        WHEN @ReportOn NOT IN  ('P','B') THEN GL2.Amount
                        WHEN GL2.GLAccountID IN (11, 12) THEN -GL2.Amount
                        WHEN GL2.GLClassificationType IN (4000, 2005) THEN  GL2.Amount
                        ELSE 0
                      END ) AS GLAmount,
                 GL2.GLAccountID,
                 CASE
                   WHEN GL2.GLClassificationType IN (4000,5002)
                   AND COALESCE(GL2.Classification,-1) NOT IN (100,200,300,400,500) THEN 100
                   ELSE GL2.Classification
                 END AS Classification,
                 GL2.GLClassificationType,
                 GL2.DivisionID,
                 GL2.IsTaxable,
                 GL2.TaxClassID,
                 GL2.GroupID,
                 TransHeader.StatusText,
                 CAST(TransHeader.Description AS VARCHAR(30)) AS Description,
                 TransHeader.DueDate,
                 TransHeader.OrderOriginName,

                 -- TransHeader Related Fields
                 GL2.TransHeaderID, 
                 TransHeader.OrderNumber,
                 COALESCE( TransHeader.InvoiceNumber, TransHeader.OrderNumber) as InvoiceNumber,
                 TransHeader.CreditMemoOrderID,
                 TransHeader.Salesperson1ID, 
                 TransHeader.OrderOriginID,
                 TransHeader.InvoiceAddressID as OrderInvoiceAddressID,
                 TransHeader.PromotionID,
                 Transheader.DiscountPrice,
                 TransHeader.PricingLevelID, 
                 TransHeader.ClosedDate,
                 TransHeader.OrderCreatedDate,
                 TransHeader.SaleDate,
                 TransHeader.BuiltDate,

                 -- TransDetail Related Fields
                 GL2.TransDetailID,
                 TransDetail.LineItemNumber,
                 TransDetail.Quantity,
                 GL2.GoodsItemID,
                 GL2.GoodsItemClassTypeID,
                 TransDetail.GoodsItemCode,

                 Station.StationName as GLDepartment,

                 -- Account Related Fields
                 GL2.AccountID,
                 ParentAccount.CompanyName,
                 ParentAccount.AccountNumber,
                 ParentAccount.PricingPlanTypeID,
                 ParentAccount.IndustryID,
                 ParentAccount.RegionID,
                 ParentAccount.OriginID as CompanyOriginID,
                 ParentAccount.Marketing3ID,
                 ParentAccount.BillingAddressID as CompanyBillingAddressID

          FROM   @GLEntries GL2
                 LEFT JOIN TransHeader WITH(NOLOCK) ON (TransHeader.ID = GL2.TransHeaderID)
                 LEFT JOIN Account WITH(NOLOCK) ON (Account.ID = GL2.AccountID)
                 LEFT JOIN Account ParentAccount WITH(NOLOCK) ON ParentAccount.ID = ( CASE WHEN @GroupSubsidiaries = 1 THEN COALESCE(Account.ParentID, Account.ID) ELSE Account.ID END )
                 LEFT JOIN TransDetail WITH(NOLOCK) ON (TransDetail.ID = GL2.TransDetailID)
                 LEFT JOIN Station WITH(NOLOCK) ON TransDetail.GLDepartmentID = Station.ID

          WHERE  ( GL2.GLClassificationType IN (4000) 
                   OR ( @ReportOn = 'B' AND GL2.GLAccountID in (12) )
                   OR ( @ReportOn = 'P' AND GL2.GLAccountID in (11,12) )
                 )


          GROUP BY GL2.EntryDateTime, 
                   GL2.GLAccountID,
                   GL2.GLAccountClassTypeID,
                   GL2.Classification,
                   GL2.GLClassificationType,
                   GL2.DivisionID,
                   GL2.IsTaxable,
                   GL2.TaxClassID,
                   GL2.GroupID,

                   -- TransHeader Related Fields
                   GL2.TransHeaderID, 
                   TransHeader.OrderNumber,
                   COALESCE( TransHeader.InvoiceNumber, TransHeader.OrderNumber ),
                   TransHeader.CreditMemoOrderID,
                   TransHeader.Salesperson1ID,
                   TransHeader.OrderOriginID,
                   TransHeader.InvoiceAddressID,
                   TransHeader.PromotionID,
                   TransHeader.PricingLevelID, 
                   Transheader.DiscountPrice,
                   TransHeader.OrderCreatedDate,
                   TransHeader.SaleDate,
                   TransHeader.ClosedDate,
                   TransHeader.BuiltDate,
                   TransHeader.StatusText,

                   TransHeader.DueDate,
                   TransHeader.OrderOriginName,
                   CAST(TransHeader.Description AS VARCHAR(30)),

                   -- TransDetail Related Fields
                   GL2.TransDetailID,
                   TransDetail.LineItemNumber,
                   TransDetail.Quantity,
                   GL2.GoodsItemID,
                   GL2.GoodsItemClassTypeID,
                   TransDetail.GoodsItemCode,

                   Station.StationName,

                   -- Account Related Fields
                   GL2.AccountID,
                   ParentAccount.CompanyName,
                   ParentAccount.AccountNumber,
                   ParentAccount.PricingPlanTypeID,
                   ParentAccount.IndustryID,
                   ParentAccount.RegionID,
                   ParentAccount.OriginID,
                   ParentAccount.Marketing3ID,
                   ParentAccount.BillingAddressID ) AS fx_Return

        LEFT JOIN EmployeeGroup WITH(NOLOCK) ON EmployeeGroup.ID = fx_Return.DivisionID 
        LEFT JOIN MarketingListItem AS Origin WITH(NOLOCK) ON Origin.ID = fx_Return.CompanyOriginID
        LEFT JOIN MarketingListItem AS CompanyOriginParent WITH(NOLOCK) ON Origin.ParentID = CompanyOriginParent.ID     
                                                                           AND Origin.ParentClassTypeID = CompanyOriginParent.ClassTypeID
        LEFT JOIN MarketingListItem AS Industry WITH(NOLOCK) ON Industry.ID = fx_Return.IndustryID
        LEFT JOIN MarketingListItem AS IndustryParent WITH(NOLOCK) ON Industry.ParentID = IndustryParent.ID 
                                                                      AND Industry.ParentClassTypeID = IndustryParent.ClassTypeID 
        LEFT JOIN MarketingListItem AS OrderOrigin WITH(NOLOCK) ON fx_Return.OrderOriginID = OrderOrigin.ID 
        LEFT JOIN MarketingListItem AS OrderOriginParent WITH(NOLOCK) ON OrderOrigin.ParentID = OrderOriginParent.ID
                                                                         AND OrderOrigin.ParentClassTypeID = OrderOriginParent.ClassTypeID
        LEFT JOIN Address WITH(NOLOCK) ON fx_Return.CompanyBillingAddressID = Address.ID
        LEFT JOIN CustomerGoodsItem AS Product WITH(NOLOCK) ON fx_Return.GoodsItemID = Product.ID
                                                               AND Product.ClassTypeID=fx_Return.GoodsItemClassTypeID
        LEFT JOIN PricingElement AS ProductCategory WITH(NOLOCK) ON Product.CategoryID = ProductCategory.ID
                                                                    AND Product.CategoryClassTypeID = ProductCategory.ClassTypeID
        LEFT JOIN PricingElement AS ProductSubCategory WITH(NOLOCK) ON ProductCategory.ParentID = ProductSubCategory.ID
                                                                       AND ProductCategory.ParentClassTypeID = ProductSubCategory.ClassTypeID
        LEFT JOIN Employee AS Salesperson1 WITH(NOLOCK) ON fx_Return.SalesPerson1ID = Salesperson1.ID 
        LEFT JOIN GLAccount WITH(NOLOCK) ON fx_Return.GLAccountID = GLAccount.ID 
        LEFT JOIN MarketingListItem AS Region WITH(NOLOCK) ON  fx_Return.RegionID = Region.ID
) AS Orders

 LEFT JOIN ( SELECT SUM( CASE 
                           WHEN @ReportOn <> 'P' THEN -GL3.Amount
                           WHEN GL3.GLAccountID IN (11, 12, 51) THEN GL3.Amount
                           WHEN GL3.GLClassificationType IN (4000, 2005)   THEN -GL3.Amount
                           ELSE 0
                         END ) AS CompanyTotalAmount,
                    COUNT(DISTINCT TransHeader.ID) AS CompanyOrderCount,
                    GL3.AccountID AS TotalsAccountID
             FROM   @GLEntries GL3 
                    LEFT JOIN TransHeader WITH(NOLOCK) ON (TransHeader.ID = GL3.TransHeaderID)

             WHERE  ( GL3.GLClassificationType in (4000) -- 5002) --Kyle/Scott, we have no clue why this was included, can't think of any expense accounts you'd ever show as a sale
                      OR
                      ( @ReportOn = 'B' AND GL3.GLAccountID in (12) )
                      OR
                      ( @ReportOn = 'P' AND GL3.GLAccountID in (11, 12) )
                    )


             GROUP BY GL3.AccountID ) AS Totals ON Totals.TotalsAccountID =  Orders.AccountID

WHERE OrderNumber IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing? If you want to store data you can store it in the staging table and truncate the table every week before running the report query.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is have a job that runs every Monday and set the script so the dates roll ( I can do that part ) and the data that is returned from the query (job) is appended to an existing table. I have no idea how to store the data in a staging table and append?

I can write queries but the SQL Server Job Agent is confusing me.

Comment: You can insert the data from this query into a table and then select from this table rather than running the query again. You can tie this all up (this query and the insert part) in a stored procedure which will be run by the SQL Agent Job.

Comment: Honestly I have no idea how to do that :(
I can write queries but I'm a little lost beyond that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) OK - so you need to create a table with the same columns and same data types as in the select list (`SELECT Orders.*, Totals.*`...) 
2) You will have to include the `insert` statement before the `select` - something like this 
 
`insert StagingTableName
 select Orders.*, Totals.*...`
3) Create a stored procedure with all your code in it.
4) Execute the stored procedure using a SQL Server Agent Job. This [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135739.aspx) should help.